# No generic method 'Where' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments

Tags: linq, iqueryable

I want to retrieve a specific record using IQueryable. But i get error 'No generic method 'Where' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.'. I got the selected row id, but I cannot display it out. Here is my code.

```
 internal static IQueryable GetRecordsFromPrimaryKeys(this IQueryable datasource, List<FilterDescriptor> primaryKeys)
    {
        IQueryable data = datasource;

        ParameterExpression paramExp = null;
        bool firstLoop = false;
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression predicate = null;

        var RecordType = datasource.GetObjectType();
        paramExp = RecordType.Parameter();

        foreach (FilterDescriptor primaryKey in primaryKeys)
        {
            if (!(firstLoop))
            {
                predicate = data.Predicate(paramExp, primaryKey.ColumnName, primaryKey.Value, FilterType.Equals, false, RecordType);
                firstLoop = true;
            }
            else
            {
                predicate = predicate.AndPredicate(data.Predicate(paramExp, primaryKey.ColumnName, primaryKey.Value, FilterType.Equals, false, RecordType));
            }
        }

        if (paramExp != null && predicate != null)
        {
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(predicate, paramExp);
            data = data.Provider.CreateQuery(
                       Expression.Call(
                       typeof(Queryable),
                       "Where",
                       new Type[] { data.ElementType },
                       data.Expression,
                       lambda
                       )
                   );

        }

        return data;
    }
```

---

My Code works well for IEnumerable/IQueryable/ICollection . But it throws the exception when i specify the class with the keyword virtual and type as ICollection. My code is

```
public class RoomType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Room code cannot be longer than 10 characters.")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Room name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RoomCategory> RoomCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Some random values gets appended to 'RecordType' while using the keyword 'virtual'. I think this leads to the exception. Still searching for the solution.

I don't know what is going wrong . Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your code should work. Are you sure all your types match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into a similar situation. The problem stems from the fact that in some cases you're dealing with the "proxy" not the actual entity. So, you want to make sure that `RecordType` matches `data.ElementType`.

try:

```
var recordType = datasource.GetObjectType();

// make sure we have the correct type (not the proxy)
if (recordType.BaseType.Name != "Object") 
    recordType = recordType.BaseType;
```

**Or better yet**, try:

```
var recordType = data.ElementType
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `typeof(Enumerable)`  instead of `typeof(Queryable)`